# Intersection of a curve with $x$ axis, Trigonometric function

Tags: functional-analysis, trigonometry

I'm trying to solve the following question:
" $f(x) = \cos^2x -a ^2 \cos x, \; a>\sqrt{2}, \; 0\leq x \leq 2\pi.$
Find the intersection point of the curve of $f$ with $x$-axis,
find the answer using a"
Now how can I find this for a trigonometric function?

Comment: f(x) is invalid. Cos² function don't have parameter

Comment: The same way you do it for a polynomial.

Comment: i have to find the answer for (a) sorry i forgot to mention that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ a>\sqrt{2}, \; 0\leq x \leq 2\pi\\
f(x) = \cos^2x -a ^2 \cos x=0 \\ \cos x(\cos x-a^2)=0 \\\to\begin{cases}\cos x=0 & x = \dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{3\pi}{2}\\\cos x=a^2 & a^2>2(there-is -no- solution)\end{cases} $$

Answer (score 0):

$ f(x)=\cos x (\cos x - a^2)$
For intersection with x-axis f(x)=0.
Implies : $\cos x (\cos x - a^2) = 0$
Hence cos x =0 {since $a>\sqrt2$}
So $x\in n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}$